# Socket.io How to make function io() anonymous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to make an application on node.js using Soket.io

### server-side

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {httpCompression: false, cookie: false});
io.on('connection', function(socket) { ... });
```

### client-side

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('ws://my-ws-server:8000/');
</script>
```

My problem:
Each client/user can write into console `mysocket=io('ws://my-ws-server');` and push new connection, so now he can `emit` signals with wrong data or spam with new Socket connections

I also tried download socket.io.js code, edit it with `$(function(){ /*socket.io code*/ });`, and when `include ../javascript/socket.io.js` to my page, but it doesn't help, io() function still accessed from console

so, is there any solution? Is here any way to hide this function and prepare from spam with new fake socket connections?

tnx, sry for my eng.

Comment: Think about this same question for any website. How would you restrict access to yourWebsite.com??

Comment: You can do anything from the console, even include your own socket.io library (or connect without it.) in other words, you're trying to fight a battle you can't win. the client has full control of the client.

Comment: @KevinB Sadly this is true. there is no 100% way of defending against an attack. Validation always helps in this matter.

Comment: Can you not check connections by IP address or something else unique? If someone is connecting repeatedly from the same location or sending huge amounts of data, there should be relatively simple ways to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to prevent malicious data from your emit by validating input message before you dispatch it. So first check if it's a string your system knows about by comparing it to your dictionary, then correct authority level clearance. If it passes then do the callback which emits the registered action. It's not 100% but it prevents your application from taking malicious information

Comment: ye, I think it's good answer, now i had new ideas, thank you ;)
the one: create something like registry, where I can write that I waiting response from socket and deny any same response signals wich not registered yet

Comment: Thanks, I've encountered the same issue and managed to solve it that way. You can also pass around an UUID with your events and you can validate this uuid as well along with your dictionary. Can you bump answer up? I am looking to unlock some cool badges :D

Comment: Oh, I made the wrong conclusions, my main problem example:
I want to ask Socket `socket.emit("whats_your_id");` , now I wait answer from Socket and I want to hear The Real user id, but if Socket was created in browser console by hand, user can avoid my script for answer and say for example he's id='4', but it is '18', now when I handle his id, I will process the data of another player, which is not correct

Comment: Have you looked into the revealing module pattern? This might help make your calls internally. This means you will have fake private and public methods and people would need to try harder to hack their user account in.This means they would never be able to add it to the window object. Check example https://jsbin.com/tuvepitohe/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Tnx, nice example(I'm newbie with js), if I understand you correctly I need to similarly try to hide the socket.io.js code with io(...)?

Comment: Yes, in combination of the things mentioned above. You will have a more secured way of communicating to your server. There isa  good course about the revealing module pattern for games on frontend masters found here https://frontendmasters.com/courses/js-fundamentals-to-functional it's not for free though. But packs a good value